# How to change size of STL container in C++

Tags: c++, memory, stl, containers

I have a piece of performance critical code written with pointers and dynamic memory.
I would like to rewrite it with STL containers, but I'm a bit concerned with performance. Is there a way to increase the size of a container without initializing the data?

For example, instead of doing

```
ptr = new BYTE[x];
```

I want to do something like

```
vec.insert(vec.begin(), x, 0);
```

However this initializes every byte to 0. Isn't there a way to just make the vector grow?
I know about reserve() but it just allocates memory, it doesn't change the size of the vector, and doesn't allows me to access it until I have inserted valid data.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: why would you want to access something that didn't contain valid data?

Comment: You shouldn't care about that. `std::vector` is a general purpose array. If you need raw speed, it's not made for that (although having been sufficiently fast for anything i've used it for yet). You should cook your own container then that cares not to uselessly initialize the items.

Comment: I have to pass a buffer to an API which tells me how much space I need.
So, in plain old C, and symplifying a bit it's:

sz = GetSizeNeeded(); buf = malloc(sz); GetBuffer(buf);

Comment: Thank you Johannes. I just wanted to be sure that I wasn't reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vec.resize( newsize )` is defined to have the same effect as

```
vec.insert( vec.end(), newsize - vec.size(), T() )
```

if `newsize > vec.size()`… but the compiler may have difficulty determining that it is growing, not shrinking, and by how much. You might try profiling with both.

If you're sure that the default initialization is taking time, explicitly eliminate it with your own constructor. (Even if the implicit constructor is fine, it's good to show intent.)

```
struct BYTE {
    char v;
    BYTE() {} // no default initialization!
    BYTE( char x ) : v(x) {}
    operator char&() { return v; }
    operator char const&() const { return v; }
    char *operator&() { return &v; } // not sure about operator&...
    char const *operator&() const { return &v; } // probably good in this case
};
```

Answer (score 4):

[vector.resize(...)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/) may be of help?  You can specify the size that you want to resize to (going larger or smaller) and also intialize what you want the new elements to be initialized to.

Answer (score 2):

resize()

It may or may not do anything different than your insert().  Values are default constructed.

Comment: Urghh, thank you. Didn't saw it. 
Anyway, if values are default constructed, I won't bet on its performance.

Comment: @Jamie: If this is the answer to your question, please upvote it by clicking the up arrow, and accept it by clicking the big check mark to the left of Noah's post.

Comment: @raven They are default constructed, but `BYTE` usually has a default constructor that is a no-op, so in that particular case, it ought to be constant time.